# Swift UICollection view different number of cells per row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can I have a UICollection View, with One cell in the first row, and three cells in the second row?

I want to display a picture in the first row, and below it 3 pictures.

Comment: using `section` for your `row`

Comment: There may be multiple ways of achieving this. One is using a table view different types of cells. One cell could have a stack view containing multiple images.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there any sample code that I can start from. I am a beginner and trying to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use collectionView's Datasource method number of section to specify how many section you required in your collectionview. in that section you can pass number of cell you want to display. and in cell for item you can set data according to section and Item value.

try like this.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3 // you can return as per your requirement
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return 2 // number of cell you want to display in each section
    }else if section == 1 {
        return 3 // number of cell you want to display in each section
    }else {
        return 4 // number of cell you want to display in each section
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierCollection, for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own custom layout. By default the collection view has [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout), that fills the cells in a horizontal/vertical grid.

You can change this behaviour with your own layout, i.e. a class implementing [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout).

To get started, I would recommend checking [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2) and [this](https://stablekernel.com/creating-a-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-in-swift/) tutorials.